# Does MySQL consume significantly more resources compared to other DBMS?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, memory-leaks, resources

There is a growing tendency for shifting from mysql to NOSQL, SQLite, etc. I have read many blogs and articles comparing the speed of mysql with other types of DBMS. However, I believe that speed is not a problem with mysql, as it is really fast; but the problem is more connected with resource usage. It is common to face extreme server load due to mysql slow queries. For instance, an advantage of Oracle over mysql is to have less problem associated with memory leaks.

1. Is it true that mysql consumes **significantly** more resources (CPU and memory) comparing with other databases such as SQLite, Non-relational databases, key/value databases. By **significantly** I mean is it the main reason for not using mysql for large databases (to save server costs).
2. If YES (to 1), what can be an estimate of better resource usage of a similar system like SQLite comparing with Mysql.

Note: Consider a simple system as advanced features of mysql is not needed. Just comparing the performance for simple queries.

Comment: Good question, but it might get more suitable responses on serverfault (where the real server admins hang out) than on stackoverflow (more programmers that will reply with "I think"). Voting to migrate.

Comment: @Konerak It probably makes even _more_ sense on the [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Konerak: Thanks for subtle edit!

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu Thanks! There's new StackExchanges coming every day. Within a few months, we'll be closing this to mysql-compared-to-other-rdbms.stackexchange.com or something.

Comment: @Konerak: This is a double-edged sword (having both advantage and disadvantage). Many of DB experts (or heavily committed to DB issues) are not aware of DBA yet; then, not checking topics there.

Comment: I attended a seminar in London in oracle office about the upcoming version of MySQL which is 6 I hope. In that all the above issues will be addressed and the new version includes a NoSQL build on it. So all I can say is please wait until the new version comes out before you decide on moving your system to part NoSQL and part MySQL..

Comment: @Karthik: That would be an amazing improvement to keep mysql users forever. Worth f waiting!

Comment: @Ali ya they made amazing improvements Oracle has invested a lot more money on MySQL to make it second most best DB.. The improvements are not only for DB but there are lot more improvements to Administration part as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU and Memory never are the reason, as they are cheap. The problem is with the I/O speed. NoSQL databases are used in write-intensive applications, as well as in applications which need schema-less database (because changing the table schema in MySQL involves rewriting the table, which may be extremely slow). So some trade-offs are made to optimize the disk operations, which often lead to consuming more CPU, memory or disk space.

Another reason could be pessimistic vs optimistic locks. Which is another topic.

But since the answer to the question "Is it true that mysql consumes significantly more resources (CPU and memory) comparing with other databases" is **NO**, it is pointless to discuss it further :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using "simple" queries, I don't think there's much of a difference regarding ressource usage between MySQL and e.g. Oracle. 
Those "professional" DBMS do a lot of "magic" regarding caching, prefetching and data maintanance. 
Of course MySQL does that as well, but it might not be as efficient for really complex databases and advanced queries.

Your choise of DBMS highly depends on what you're planning to do, especially if you're choosing between SQL/NoSQL/Key-Value/..., which are for *completely* different scenarios… that's not so much a question of memory and CPU usage.

Comment: Consider a simple scenario (two-column table) which fit within all cases. I believe that CPU load of mysql is much more than MongoDB, BerkeleyDB, etc.

Comment: It might be higher, yes. But I think (you never know without trying…) that with a good index, query caching and table caching you will get pretty good performance as well. But a DBMS that's built speficially for key-value-storage is more optimized of course – so you might trade flexibility for performance.